# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/bin/firefox) on port 7055

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, java-8, webdriver, robotframework

While running the robot test cases in jenkins, Below are the errors we are encountering for the test cases after running the build in CI jenkins:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
code.com":{"d":"/tmp/anonymous22248968795791837webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.43.1","st":1692883457000,"mt":1692883457000}},"app-system-defaults":{"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/opt/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.5","st":1692880913000},"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/opt/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.9","st":1692880913000},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"d":"/opt/firefox/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1692880913000},"aushelper@mozilla.org":{"d":"/opt/firefox/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"2.0","st":1692880913000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/opt/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"52.0","st":1692880913000}}}
1692883459521   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1692883459531   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /opt/firefox/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1692883459532   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /opt/firefox/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1692883459538   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelpe...
    [ Message content over the limit has been removed. ]
...9827 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1692883459830   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1692883459845   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1692883459845   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1692883459845   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1692883459965   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1692883459965   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1692883459966   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
```

Even i used the compatibility versions of browser and webdriver, below is the reference link:
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

So because of the above errors we are unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

These errors are resolved now after adding some arguments for Open Browser in test case.
After Open Browser - the below arguments are needed

```
url, browser=firefox, alias=None, remote_url=False, desired_capabilities=None, ff_profile_dir=None
```